# Setting the DNS of all containers in a docker-compose

Tags: docker, networking, dns, docker-compose

Is it possible to set the same DNS to all container in a docker-compose file at once instead of having to put it explicitly on each container ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I've found is to edit DOCKER_OPTS in file /etc/default/docker with `DOCKER_OPTS="--dns x.x.x.x --dns y.y.y.y"`
And then in /lib/systemd/system/docker.service, make sure that there is an EnvironmentFile defined and that the DOCKER_OPTS are used in ExecStart

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// $DOCKER_OPTS
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/docker
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way would be to change the daemon configuration:

```
# /etc/docker/daemon.json
{ "dns": ["8.8.8.8", "8.8.4.4"] }
```